# Same context menu displayed for TreeViewItem

Tags: wpf, treeview

I have a WPF TreeView and some of the TreeViewItems have a context menu. For example,
Root and Node 2 do not have a context menu, but Node 1 does. After the window is loaded, when I right click on Node 2 or Root for the first time I don't see a context menu and upon clicking on Node 1, context menu is displayed, so far good. Now when I click on Node 2, I am seeing a context menu, but I am not assigning any context menu to that 'Node 2' treeviewitem.

[image: TreeView]

Event:

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseRightButtonDown" Handler="OnPreviewMouseRightButtonDown" />
                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Event Handler:

```
private void OnPreviewMouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var obj = e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject;
            var item = GetDependencyObjectFromVisualTree(obj, typeof(TreeViewItem)) as TreeViewItem;
            if (item == null) return;
            item.Focus();
            item.IsSelected = true;
            var selectedElement = (XmlElement)item.Header;
            string type = selectedElement.GetAttribute("Type");

            if (type.ToLower().Trim() == "Node 1")
            {
                var menuitem1 = new MenuItem(); menuitem1.Header = "New..."; menuitem1.Width = Double.NaN;
                var menuitem2 = new MenuItem(); menuitem2.Header = "Open...";

                var menu = new ContextMenu() { };
                menu.Items.Add(menuitem1);
                menu.Items.Add(menuitem2);
                (sender as TreeViewItem).ContextMenu = menu;
            }
            else
            {
                (sender as TreeViewItem).ContextMenu = null;
            }

            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

I tried assigning Null to context menu, but no use. When I debug, I could see that no context menu is being assigned to the TreeViewItem, but even then is displayed.

Comment: when did you set `ContextMenu` to `null`? Just a quick fix to your code, I think you can try adding the `else` statement (to your `if(type.ToLower().Trim() == "Node 1")`) like this `... else { (sender as TreeViewItem).ContextMenu = null;}`.

Comment: I tried setting ContextMenu to null, but still it is getting displayed.

Comment: I found a workaround though:`var temp = new ContextMenu();
                temp.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                (sender as TreeViewItem).ContextMenu = temp;`

Comment: not sure why it's so bothering that way. Normally setting it to `null` should work. Anyway all the code you wrote is not what you should do in WPF. Almost everything related to UI can be done in XAML code, it's much cleaner and better.